# Network/Proxy Authentication (WebClient.UseDefaultCredentials alternative)

Tags: java, c#, networking, proxy

I am writing a program in java that must be run in my workplace environment.
Here is a snippet of my code:

```
URL url = new URL("www.google.com");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
```

On my home network, this works perfectly fine, but on the business network, I get this error:

> java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv
>   failed    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)  at
>   Conquerer.run(Conquerer.java:44)

I am pretty sure this has something to do with the network setup here.  However, when I write a C# program, I can use `WebClient.UseDefaultCredentials(true);` to fix the problem.
Is there a version of this that I can use for my java program?

---

Here are a few more details that might help:

- I can connect to the wifi with my phone, but I cannot use the internet.  I can ping the phone to ensure it is on the network, but I cannot get internet access.
- The network is windows based.  If I use my personal laptop (windows 8), I get popups that ask me to enter my credentials before using the internet.  When I enter my credentials, I DO get internet (chrome), but the java program still cannot connect.
- I do not have the url of the proxy server being used
- I do have administrator privileges, and running it in Administrative mode does not fix the problem.

Comment: Based on the first detail, I do NOT understand how you could ever get a response (the recv error) if you cannot access the internet

Comment: I can access the internet (using chrome, firefox, IE) but any program that ever tries to use an external connection will not work (like self-updating software). I specifically said, "I DO get internet (chrome), but the java program still cannot connect."

Answer (score 1):

From detail #1, I'm guessing you're company uses a proxy.  The reason Firefox, Chrome, IE, etc is these were setup by the IT department.

Check your proxy settings [in each browser](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-Proxy-Settings), and see if anything has been set.

My guess as to why C# worked is the proxy settings are in IE, and C# is pulling those in.  I'd also go to your IT department for help, as the issue is almost certainly related to the network setup.